# Cell array mean in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell, mean

I do simulation studies on linear model y=X*beta+eps with size(X)=[n d].
I consider the effect of dimensionality d based on two methods.
I run 10 simulated datas and get corresponding beta estimates, and then
I want to compute the mean of beta across the 10 simulated datas.

My toy matlab code is as follows:

```
        nsim=10;   %iteration number
        dd=[4 6];  %two dimension cases,\beta=(\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_d)^T
        ddlen=length(dd);
        nmethod=2; %two methods
        seednum=0;

        BH  = cell(nsim,ddlen,nmethod); %estimation of beta w.r.t two dimension cases and two methods

        for di = 1:ddlen
            d = dd(di);
            for ni = 1:nsim
                seednum = seednum + di*ni;
                randn('seed', seednum);
                betahat=randn(d,1); 
                for method = 1:nmethod
                    if method==1
                        BH{ni,di,method} = betahat;
                    else
                        BH{ni,di,method} = 10*betahat;
                    end
                end
            end
        end
```

Then we can obtain

```
BH(:,:,1) = 

    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]


BH(:,:,2) = 

    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
```

I want the mean across 10 rows (nsim=10) and get something like

```
mean(BH(:,:,1))= 

    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]

mean(BH(:,:,2)) = 

    [4x1 double]    [6x1 double]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks@EBH.  But your answer is not that I want.  The return should be two vectors, one is [4x1 double] and the other is  [6x1 double], and in other words, the mean of 10 [4x1 double] and the mean of 10 [6x1 double] respectively.

Comment: Why are you using cell arrays if all of your arrays are the same size?

Comment: why do you set a new random seed on every loop?

Comment: So the simulation resulut can be reproducible@EBH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the most efficient way do do that but you can use `arrayfun` for that:

```
% generate random array
BH = repmat({rand(4,1),rand(6,1)},[10 1 2]);
% generate indexes for the 2nd and 3rd dimensions
[n2,n1] = meshgrid(1:size(BH,2),1:size(BH,3));
% get mean across 1st (cell) dimension
[res] = arrayfun(@(n1,n2)mean([BH{:,n1,n2}],2),n1(:),n2(:),'UniformOutput',false);
% reshape to desired output
res = reshape(res,[1 size(BH,2) size(BH,3)]);
```

In case you want to generalize to an N-dimensional cell array:

```
% generate random array
BH = repmat({rand(4,1),rand(6,1)},[10,1,2,2,5]);
sz = size(BH);
% generate indexes for the 2nd and 3rd dimensions
n = cell(1,numel(sz) - 1);
[n{:}] = ndgrid(1:sz(2),1:sz(3),1:sz(4),1:sz(5));
n = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) {x(:)},n));
idx = 1:size(n,1);
% get mean across 1st (cell) dimension
[res] = arrayfun(@(idx)mean([BH{:,n(idx,1),n(idx,2),n(idx,3),n(idx,4)}],2),...
    idx,'UniformOutput',false);
% reshape to desired output
res = reshape(res,[1 sz(2:end)]);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks@user2999345. Well, I find it is a little bit complicated to do some generalization accoding to your approach. Just Think about   `BH = repmat({rand(4,1),rand(6,1)},[10,1,2,2,5]);`  i.e., 10 iterations, 2 dimenalities, 2 noise levels and 5 candidate methods for linear model y=X*beta+eps, where eps~N(0,\sigma^2*I), and \sigma is the noise level

Comment: Wow, your new edit answer is fantastic! Thanks a lot! @user2999345

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to take the mean over all the elements that in the same position in the vector. So from all the vectors in `BH(:,1,1)` we obtain one vector of 4 means, each one for a position in the vector. The same holds for `BH(:,1,2)`. For `BH(:,2,1)` and `BH(:,2,1)` we do the same but with 6 elements in a vector.

You can use the following code for that:

```
% split BH to 2 arrays:
bh4 = reshape(cell2mat(BH(:,1,:)),[],nsim,2); % all the 4 elements vectors
bh6 = reshape(cell2mat(BH(:,2,:)),[],nsim,2); % all the 6 elements vectors
meanBH4 = squeeze(mean(bh4,2)); % mean over all 4 element vectors
meanBH6 = squeeze(mean(bh6,2)); % mean over all 6 element vectors
```

However, one step in the right way to do this would be to define two arrays, one for each method:

```
BH1  = zeros(nsim,ddlen,dd(1));
BH2  = zeros(nsim,ddlen,dd(2));
```

then in your loop assign the values to them:

```
if method==1
    BH1(ni,di,:) = betahat;
else
    BH2(ni,di,:) = 10*betahat;
end
```

and at the end just take the mean of each:

```
meanBH1 = mean(BH1,3)
meanBH2 = mean(BH1,3)
```

---

**EDIT:**

To write all this in a more 'Matlabish' way I would suggest the following:

```
nsim = 10;   % iteration number
dd = [4 6];  % two dimension cases,\beta=(\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_d)^T
methods = 2; % two methods

% preapering random seeds
s = bsxfun(@times,1:numel(dd),(1:nsim).');
seednum = cumsum(s(:));

% initialize results array
BH = nan(max(dd),nsim,numel(dd),methods);
counter = 1;
for k = 1:numel(dd)
    for n = 1:nsim
        % set a new random seed from the list:
        rng(seednum(counter));
        % compute all betahats with this seed:
        betahat = randn(max(dd),2).*repmat([1 10],[max(dd) 1]);
        % assign the values to BH by dimension:
        for m = 1:methods
            BH(1:dd(k),n,k,m) = betahat(1:dd(k),m);
        end
        counter = counter+1;
    end
end
% compute the means over iterations:
means = squeeze(mean(BH,2,'omitnan'))
```

and so you get `means` as your result.

---

P.S. I don't know why you call `randn('seed', seednum)` on every iteration, [besides that's not a recommended syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/updating-your-random-number-generator-syntax.html), but you if you can delete it then you can vectorize most of the loops, and your code squeezes to:

```
% compute all betahats:
betahat = randn(nsim,max(dd),numel(dd),2);
% apply dimensions:
for k = dd
    betahat(:,k+1:end,1,:) = nan;
end
% apply methos 2:
betahat(:,:,:,2) = betahat(:,:,:,2)*10;

% compute the means over iterations:
means = squeeze(mean(betahat,1,'omitnan'))
```

Hope things looks clearer now...

Comment: Thanks@EBH.  But your answer is not that I want.  The return should be two vectors, one is [4x1 double] and the other is  [6x1 double], and in other words, the mean of 10 [4x1 double] and the mean of 10 [6x1 double] respectively.

Comment: @JohnStone what you describe in the question is a 1*2*2 output, and not to vectors of 4*1 and 6*1 output. However, see my edit for this.

Comment: Thanks@EBH. Well, if I consider a more complex setting such as `BH = repmat({rand(4,1),rand(6,1)},[10,1,2,2,5]);` i.e., 10 iterations, 2 dimenalities, 2 noise levels and 5 candidate methods for linear model y=X*beta+eps, where eps~N(0,\sigma^2*I), and \sigma is the noise level. What I should do?

Comment: Your **A correct approach to this would be to define two arrays, one for each method** is a nice solution way! @EBH

Comment: @JohnStone keep in mind that working with cell arrays is not recommended, especially if you want your code to be quick and unconstrained by the shape of the input. See me **EDIT** for a way to write your code with ND-arrays instead of cell arrays. If you want to run this over many possibilities and iterations - that would be a much better way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
% split into seperate cell arrays
BH_1 = BH(:,:,1);
BH_2 = BH(:,:,2);

% create matrix of compatible vectors, and take mean and put result back into cell array
BH_1_mean = cat(2,{mean(cell2mat(BH_1(:,1)'),2)}, {mean(cell2mat(BH_1(:,2)'),2)});
BH_2_mean = cat(2,{mean(cell2mat(BH_2(:,1)'),2)}, {mean(cell2mat(BH_2(:,2)'),2)});
```